# Material UI Stack first child component isn't indented correctly?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Not sure if this is some CSS issue that I can fix, but I am trying to use a `<Stack />` from Material UI to construct a vertical list of checkboxs with labels.

I've attempted the following in the sandbox here (see demo.tsx): https://codesandbox.io/embed/basicstack-material-demo-forked-q8kb4q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

With the code here

```
export default function BasicStack() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="Test1" />
        <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="Test2" />
        <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="Test3" />
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

As you can see in the demo, ONLY the first child component isn't lined up correctly so a temporary solution is to add a `sx={{marginLeft: 0.1}}` only to the first `<FormControlLabel />` which I think isn't a great practice. Does anyone know why this misalignment happens? And if there is a more elegant way of fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on the spacing=2, you can try to remove it, and then the indented will correct.

```html
<Stack>
  <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="Test1" />
  <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="Test2" />
  <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="Test3" />
</Stack>
```

[image]